# Deleting older records from a table that is constantly getting used

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table 'ActivityLog' that is constantly getting used. It captures all activities of different users like the user logged, clicked on this page, did this action and so on. It is heavily used for inserts and read.

This table is currently having 5 years of data and having billions of records. I want to keep recent 2 years of data and want to remove older data. There is no downtime, I cannot take system offline for some time. I have to do this activity parallelly and the system should be not affected.

I have created a script that will take 1 day at a time and then divides the 1 day worth of data into batches of 2000 records. It will delete 2000 records at a time and then move on to next.

```
DELETE AL WITH (ROWLOCK)
FROM ActivityLog AL 
INNER JOIN ActivityLogBatchTemp AB ON AL.Id = AB.ActivityLogId
WHERE AB.BatchNum = @I;
```

ActivityLogBatchTemp table is used for batching logic. BatchNum of 1 is assigned for first 2000 records, BatchNum of 2 is assigned for next 2000 records, and so on.

Referring to Microsoft [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/resolve-blocking-problems-caused-lock-escalation), I will be running below code in new SSMS window, before I run my script of deleting records:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT * FROM ActivityLog(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE 1 = 0;
WAITFOR DELAY '1:00:00';
COMMIT TRAN;
```

This will basically take and 'IX' lock on the table ActivityLog for 1 hour so that it prevents other sessions to take 'X' lock on the table. I will run my script of deleting the records 1 day at a time, before the 1 hour limit is breached. I can then continue using the same approach again.

I have put (ROWLOCK) in my script, so that it takes the lock only at row level. I am deleting 2000 records at a time, which is less than 5000, which is the current threshold for lock escalation. I am putting the 'IX' lock on the table as suggested by Microsoft.

On the lower environments like DEV and QA it seems to be working as expected. I mean, it is taking locks at the row level while deleting (and not at the table level). And an 'IX' lock is held on the table for 1 hour. However, lower environments don't match the workload of production.

Is there anything that can go wrong here? I want to avoid lock escalation to table level by my deletion script. How can I be sure that lock escalation will not happen on production environment with this approach.

You can capture extended events to see if lock escalation has happened, but I don't want to capture them, as it might affect performance.

Comment: i have no idea about the locking stuff, but you could technically do something like this: copy all data > 2 years into a new table ahead of time, put trigger in your current table that copies all new data incoming data into the new table as well, then at some point in time, do a sp_rename thing which switches out the tables, and then you're done.

Comment: As you are running in Azure SQL database the benefit to batching will probably be mostly avoiding maxing out your DTU/Resources for long contiguous period- other "usual" reasons for batching (blowing up transaction log + lock escalation) are less applicable with [ADR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/accelerated-database-recovery?view=azuresql) and with [Optimised locking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/optimized-locking?view=azuresqldb-current#what-is-optimized-locking)

Comment: The question is fair but should be migrated to DBA.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged Azure SQL database.

In that case you should likely remove all of these explicit locking hints and forget about lock escalation.

Running

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT * FROM ActivityLog(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE 1 = 0;
WAITFOR DELAY '1:00:00';
COMMIT TRAN;
```

will certainly prevent it (for an hour) but your `DELETE` process shouldn't be causing it anyway.

You are coding for a model which is no longer applicable in Azure SQL Database and should get your code working *with* the new model rather than against it.

With the [Optimized locking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/optimized-locking?view=azuresqldb-current) feature (GA in some regions in Feb 2023 and in all regions by May 2023) the default behaviour of the product is to release the row/page locks as soon as the corresponding writes are done anyway (rather than at the end of the statement/transaction). So it should never hold enough row/page locks to trigger a lock escalation.

But you must [Remove the locking hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/optimized-locking?view=azuresqldb-current#avoid-locking-hints) here to get this behaviour.

So instead your batch size should be based on whatever level is reasonable for a single process to consume without maxing out SKU resource limits for too long and affecting other processes via resource throttling waits.

Additionally you may want to keep delete statement duration short if you see blocking on the "Transaction ID" resource - due to concurrent queries that are

- trying to read the deleted rows
- not reading at some variant of snapshot isolation.

But note the above is not equivalent to lock escalation. Queries that don't try and read the deleted rows or are using snapshot isolation to do so should not be blocked. The cause is not an escalation to table lock after <magic_number> of locks.

Comment: I checked my production azure db and optimized locking is enabled for it. But last time, when I executed this activity on production with granularity of 1 day data which is around deletion of 100K records at a time, some of the other application process which were reading from this table started to time out. And I had to stop this activity.

Comment: When was that "last time"? Optimized locking is a newish feature - went GA in Feb 2023 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-sql-general-availability-updates-for-midfebruary-2023/ and wasn't available in all regions until May https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/aec2a780f555a2b6bb34f94b7416d8b818ead373

Comment: Last time was 20-Aug-2023, so it would have included optimized locking feature and it still blocked other processes.

Comment: Did you include any locking hints? You need to not do that. Apart from that did you look at the wait types for the queries that were timing out? It might have been resource based rather than locks

Comment: I did not add any locking hints during that time. Hence, I plan to use locking hints this time. I did not check during that time, what queries were timing out, but in the logs it was mentioned about timeout on access of ActivityLog table.

Comment: Well not possible for me to debug what was happening for you then. All I can tell you is that you should forget about your current approach and make sure you use Optimized locking effectively. If you do see blocking you need to investigate what is causing this. Do you have queries that are not using snapshot isolation that are trying to access the deleted rows - as no suitable index to avoid reading them? If so they could be blocked waiting for the `TID` lock on the transaction that deleted them so make sure you don't do that or keep the transaction duration short

Comment: i.e. in the last time given that optimized locking feature was in place it isn't even clear that lock escalation was the problem as it shouldn't have kicked in - and sounds like you didn't look at the resources being waited on to determine what the actual issue was

Answer (score 0):

There is a video in which Brent Ozar explains how StackOverflow works.

The StackOvderflow's database is constantly hit by user clicking the thumbs up. But every time a user click that button that doesn't correspond to an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

Instead the `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` are cached at application level. Then every minute the cache is released to the database, and there thousands of `INSERT` or `UPDATE` happens.

In an ideal world [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/maximizing-azure-sql-database-performance-with-a-globally-distributed-redis-write-behind-cache/) should be your solution.

But because you don't live in an ideal world I suggest you to scale your Azure SQL Database to [Business Critical or Premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/912341/azure-sql-server-database-read-only-copy) tier and use read-only replicas to [offload read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out?view=azuresql) query workloads.

This might reduce the stess on your database.

Then try to `DELETE`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Caching can be long term solution and it has to be implementated at application level. However, this does not answer my problem.

Comment: Wait, but I suggested you to use offload read-only. That will significantly reduce the workload. Have you tried that pattern? I't easier to setup @CleanBold

Comment: Our production database is already P6:1000 DTU which provides one read only replica and we have already offloaded the read only queries to that replica. However, DELETE will always happen on the primary db server.

Comment: Overall I think you are doing it right. You are using `DELETE AL WITH (ROWLOCK)`, you are offloading the read to another DB. There is nothing else you can do. But your question is good, try to post it here and Brent might reply you: https://pollgab.com/room/brento